# Changing length of armature/mesh withouth changing other proportions

Tags: animation, armature

I have made an opening door which is opened using wires going over supports and attached to the middle of the door. The opening works fine, but the wires are reduced in diameter when they are shortened as seen in the video. Each wire has it's own armature and I have just changed the size of those armatures so that the length matches the position of the door. Is there any way to shorten the armature without changing other proportions?

Video showing the problem: [tekfixweb.fi/video/EFGE-door.mp4](https://tekfixweb.fi/video/EFGE-door.mp4)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you didn't gave us any useful information how you solved your opening by rigging.

I rebuild your scenario with a stretch-to bone constraint for the rope and chose "maintain volume" none

[image]

that worked for me:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will try that. This is one of my absolutely first animations so I don't know if I have done it right... My animation setup looks different from yours - no empties in mine. I have just added an armature and connected it to the mesh using Ctrl+P. One armature for each part of the door.